# Nginx fpm Laravel container inside kubernetes not picking up the environment variables

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, kubernetes, environment-variables

I have one laravel docker container which is build with a custom nginx + php-fpm docker image.

I have deployed successfully to a k8s cluster and can access properly, also logging into the pod and running `env` I can see all the environment variables being set successfully from my k8s `configmap`

In the laravel code I read the environment variables like this:
For example at `SomeController.php` have the following code:

```
$apiCode = env('API_CODE');
// also tried like this $apiCode = getenv('API_CODE'); still not successful in fetching
```

My problem and this question is that the env vars are always read empty inside the php code even though inside the pod with `env` command I can see them properly set, somehow the php code cannot find them.

(I am not caching laravel config so that case we can exclude, also tried with the command `php artisan config:clear` beforehand, still same result cannot fetch the env vars within the php)

In the kubernetes definition yml I attach the configmap to env variables like below and see them defined properly inside pod:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api
  labels:
    tier: api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api
          image: somenging-fpm-image:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: api-config-env-file
```

For the moment I am lost and without any idea why this might happen.

I thought initially that maybe configmap was created late after pod started (php fpm somehow process then did not pick on start the env)

To verify and exclude that case, I destroyed the pod and recreated the deployment+pod in order to use the already existing configmap, and still the result was the same php did not pick up the env vars that were present in pod

I could log into pod by `kubectl exec -it [podnamehere] /bin/bash` and run `env` there and could see properly env vars set from my configmap `api-config-env-file`, but the code would always have them empty not be able to read them

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problems only when there are `redis` or caching system.

But you already state that

> (I am not caching laravel config so that case we can exclude, also tried with the command php artisan config:clear beforehand, still same result cannot fetch the env vars within the php)

So double check if you run any command like `php artisan optimize`. It will save the cache to redis, and the laravel application will pick the setting up from there.

Just to make sure you don't miss anything.

Try:
`php artisan optimize:clear`

This command will do the following:

```sh
Cached events cleared!
Compiled views cleared!
Application cache cleared!
Route cache cleared!
Configuration cache cleared!
Compiled services and packages files removed!
Caches cleared successfully!
```